# Django 500 internal server error Apache when using WSGI

Tags: django, apache

Help: I have am showing the following errors and can't for the life of me figure it out.

![Error log

---

when I run ./manage.py runserver 0:8080 all works fine 
but when i run apache i get the above errors.

AX1.wsgi looks like this:

```
 - import os import sys

   sys.path.append('/usr/local/ax1/')
   sys.path.append('/usr/local/ax1/ax1')

   root = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')
   sys.path.insert(0, root)


   sys.path = ['/usr/local'] + sys.path


   os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ax1.settings' import
   django.core.handlers.wsgi application =
   django.core.handlers.wsgi.WSGIHandler()
```

I ran chmod 777  -R  on the directories to make sure permissions weren't the issue ...

help would be appreciated..

Comment: `0:8080`?...`0` is not a valid IP...

Comment: 0:8080 means that bind the port on all available IP addresses.

Comment: This question needs relevant Apache configuration files, the layout of files and entries from Apache log, with debug log level, so that people can point out what could be the issue.

Comment: Apache conf file:
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName ax1.local

ServerAlias ax1
ServerAdmin it@newterra.com

DocumentRoot /usr/local/www/documents

<Directory /usr/local/documents>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
Require all granted

</Directory>

WSGIScriptAlias /axapp /usr/local/ax1.wsgi

<Directory /usr/local>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all